# Export Unity3D Project as Android Project via Command Line

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, export

we would like to export a project from unity as android project (to import it later into android studio) via command line.

Unity provides following command line arguments:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

Unfortunately there seems to be no direct option to do this. There is some scripting support to build an android project via

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.html

what would be the easiest way to export the packages from command line? should we use "-executeMethod " via command line and execute some class, that does all of this after startup?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the -executemethod to call a static build method in your project. At some point in this method you should call the following line to build your project:

```
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenePaths, buildPath, buildTarget,
                             BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer);
```

The "BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer" part tells Unity to export the eclipse project.